# How can I set a query result in a ComboBox in microsoft access?

Tags: events, ms-access

I have a form where I added two combo Box named 'Pname' and 'CompanyNameComboBox'. When I change or update the value of 'Pname' then 'CompanyNameComboBox' will be populated with the following query result:

```
SELECT tblusers.usrcmpny
FROM tblusers
WHERE (((tblusers.usrnme)=[Forms]![Adjustments Form]![Pname]));
```

this query works fine but I can not understand how can I do this. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do that in your **PName selectedindexchanged** event

```
Private Sub PNama_SelectedIndexChanged( ... ) Handles ...

   SELECT tblusers.usrcmpny FROM tblusers WHERE (((tblusers.usrnme)=[Forms]![Adjustments Form]![Pname]));

End Sub
```